# .httaccess password protection not working on recently updated browsers

Tags: htaccess, safari, mac

My situation is this: I have a web folder on an Apache server protected with standard .httaccess password protection. It's been working fine for years and the code hasn't been modified in any way. In the past few days I've noticed that it's not working on my iPhone (using Safari browser) and a Safari browser on a mac which I believe was recently updated. Still works fine on older browsers on various other computers I've tested it on.

The details of how it's not working: Normal behavior is you go to the page and get a user/passwd prompt. If you fill it in correctly it displays the file directory. If you fill in incorrect credentials you get a standard "unauthorized user" message. Current (bad) behavior (on browsers described above) is you go to the page, it does not pop the user/passwd prompt and immediately shows "unauthorized user" message. HOWEVER, if you refresh the page it does show the passwd prompt.

I'm guessing that something about a recent Safari update (possibly specific to Mac versions) has kludged things. Anyone have a similar experience or insight? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like the browser is caching the last result page for the URL. Unless you can change the header code of the not authorized page as to prevent caching, this would be considered normal browser behavior. Not all browsers behave the same all the time.